# Should I prevent circular referencing?

Tags: publications, citations

I put an article on the Arxiv, submitted it, it got cited before being accepted, and now is accepted with minor revisions. Some of the minor revisions can be implemented elegantly be referencing the article that cited the preprint version of the article.

Is it oke to do so? Or should this circular referencing be avoided?

Comment: I don’t know if you get notified of this, but please see the duplicate notice above.